# how to expose webscoket endpoint on Azure VM

Tags: java, azure, websocket, virtual-machine

I have a VM running on Azure and a java Websocket server application that is listening on a port I specify. when I run it locally on my computer it runs fine but on the VM I think I need to expose an endpoint for the websocket. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Use Azure Management Portal
- Navigate to "Virtual Machines"
- Navigate to your particular Virtual Machine
- Click on "Endpoints" tab
- Click on "+ Add" opton on the bottom to add an endpoint

do not forget to configure local firewall rules on your VM to allow for this port to be opened.  Adding the endpoint from the Azure portal only opens Load Balancer's ports

HTH